# Appending a doubly circular linked list to the end of another doubly circular list (Python)

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

So I have an assignment that ask me to append a doubly circular linked list to the end of another doubly circular list. For example, I have two doubly circular linked lists which are [0,1,2,3] and [10,11,12,13]. The output should be [0,1,2,3,10,11,12,13], and we also have to make it reversed which is [13,12,11,10,3,2,1,0]

My assignment provides two py files. The first one is called "linked_list.py". It's for creating a doubly circular linked list. I cannot modify this file.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.data = x
        self.next = None
        self.pre = None

class DoubleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertHead(self, x):
        self.head = Node(x)
        self.head.next = self.head
        self.head.pre = self.head

    def insert(self, y, x):
        tmp = self.head
        nodex = Node(x)
        while True:
            if tmp.data == y:
                break
            tmp = tmp.next
        nodex.next = tmp.next
        nodex.pre = tmp
        tmp.next.pre = nodex
        tmp.next = nodex

    def printForward(self):
        print("Forward :",end=" ")
        tmp = self.head
        print(tmp.data,end=" ")
        tmp = tmp.next
        while tmp!=self.head:
            print(tmp.data,end=" ")
            tmp=tmp.next
        print()

    def printBackward(self):
        print("Backward :",end=" ")
        tmp = self.head.pre
        print(tmp.data,end=" ")
        tmp = tmp.pre
        while tmp!=self.head.pre:
            print(tmp.data,end=" ")
            tmp=tmp.pre
        print()
```

The second code is "combine.py"

```
from linked_list import Node, DoubleLinkedList

def combine(l1, l2):
    
#This is the main part of this assignment, write a function that can combine two doubly circular linked lists. 
#There's no need to return value since we directly modify LL1 as our final result

if __name__=="__main__":
    LL1 = DoubleLinkedList()
    LL1.insertHead(0)
    LL1.insert(0, 1)
    LL1.insert(1, 2)
    LL1.insert(2, 3) #LL1 = [0,1,2,3]
    print(LL1)

    LL2 = DoubleLinkedList()
    LL2.insertHead(10)
    LL2.insert(10, 11)
    LL2.insert(11, 12)
    LL2.insert(12, 13) #LL2 = [10,11,12,13]
    print(LL2)

    combine(LL1, LL2)
    LL1.printForward()  # This function can print the combined linked list
    LL1.printBackward() # This function can reverse the 
    
    # Forward output : 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13
    # Backward output : 13 12 11 10 3 2 1 0
```

At first I was thinking about using the same method as appending normal linked list but I realized that the last node of circular linked list will point at the first node. Then I got confused by the whole assignment. How can I make one doubly circular linked list get appended to the end of another doubly circular linked list? Some detailed explanations are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to use the existing methods on the `DoubleLinkedList` class to do so, or are you free to access/change the `next` and `pre` properties directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will need to append the complete `l2` chain between `head` and `head.pre` of `l1`. In order to do so, I see two different methods:

1. The naive one (complexity: `O(n)`)

Simply reuse the methods that were nicely provided to you. In the end, you are just asked to add multiple values at the end of `l1`:

```py
def combine(l1, l2):
    l1_tail_val = l1.head.pre.data
    l2_head = l2.head
    l1.insert(l1_tail_val, l2_head.data)
    l2_head = l2_head.next
    l1_tail_val = l2_head.data
    while l2_head != l2.head:
        l1.insert(l1_tail_val, l2_head.data)
        l1_tail_val = l2_head.data
        l2_head = l2_head.next
```

This method will need to iterate over `l2` entirely, so if the list is big, it can take some time.

Edit: This is even worse than that, since in order to find the insert place, the `insert` method will iterate over `l1`, **always to find that the wanted insert location is at the end**. So this is closer to `O(n^2)` than `O(n)`

2. The efficient one (complexity: `O(1)`)

With this one, you don't have to iterate over anything, you just need to connect the nodes so that it forms a single circular list:

```py
def combine(l1, l2):
    l1_tail = l1.head.pre
    l1_head = l1.head
    l2_tail = l2.head.pre
    l2_head = l2.head

    # Now just update the references
    # Then end of l2 should be connected to the head of l1 (same for the reverse relation)
    l1_head.pre = l2_tail
    l2_tail.next = l1_head
    
    # The start of l2 should be connected to the end of l1 (same for the reverse relation)
    l1_tail.next = l2_head
    l2_head.pre = l1_tail
```

This does not rely on any loop or recursion, thus giving you a constant complexity, no matter the lists lengths

Comment: Thanks for explaining my problem. But I have a question. Why is the time complexity of the second code is O(1)?

Comment: Because we're never iterating on anything. Even if the two lists are thousands of elements long, we will be only dealing with the heads and their `pre` nodes. So the computation complexity is actually constant